# Eloquent where over multiple tables at once with a nested json result like 'with' does

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to filter a list of immigrants based on possibly many parameters (like their religion, name, current address and so on) but the data is stored in multiple tables (religions have their own table for example). I would also like to use the 'with' function to get a nested json output like:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "birthdate": "1996-08-13",
  "person": {
    "name": "Lorem",
    "street": "Ipsum"
  }
  ...
}
```

In addition to that I don't know the exact filters, because they are included in the request json (column, operator, value and maybe table if needed), so I can not hardcode them.

I am currently doing a foreach over the filters and tried to use nested whereHas with no success.
I tried the join functionality of the builder, and it worked but the json was not nested.

```
return Migrant::with('Person.Ort', ...(many other tables))->whereHas('Person', function($q) use($filter) {
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        $q->whereAnd($key, $value['operator'], $value['value']);
    }
})->get();
```

This works, but as you would guess only for filters involving the 'Person' table and not one of the possible other tables.

Is it possible to do something like this with eloquent?

EDIT:
For clarification, I want to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Migrant INNER JOIN Persons ON Migrant.id = Persons.id INNER JOIN Countries ON Migrant.country = Countries.id INNER JOIN ... WHERE Persons.name = "Lorem" AND Countries.country = "Disneyland" AND ...
```

Comment: could you post your complete function

Comment: Do you know the which filter element is for which table in advance ?

Comment: This function is part of a restful api, and this is currently everything in the immigrant filter request. The function should return the resulted collection to json_encode it.

Comment: The filter request contains information for every desired filter with the following information: key (for example name), operator (for example = or like), value, and the table the key comes from (so person for example)

Comment: could you show the structure of your `$filter `. I want to know if it is possible to get filter for specific table by using  `$filter['table_name']`

Comment: It is an array with the following structure: {"key": {"value": "Some Value", "operator": "=", "table": "Person"}}

Comment: if it is possible, see my answer. Not sure if it is the one you want. Let me know regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Migrant::with([
'Person.table1'=>function($query) use($filter){
    $query->where($filter['table1']['key'], $filter['table1']['operator'], $filter['table1']['value']);
},
'Person.table2'=>function($query) use($filter){
    $query->where($filter['table2']['key'], $filter['table2']['operator'], $filter['table2']['value']);
}])->get();
```

### Update:

```
$mainQuery = Migrant::with('Person.Ort', ...(many other tables));

if($filter['table1']){
    $mainQuery = $mainQuery->whereHas('table1', function($q) use($filter) {

        $q->whereAnd($filter['table1']['key'], $filter['table1']['operator'], $filter['table1']['value']);

})
}
.
.

return $mainQuery->get();
```

### Update 2:

```
$mainQuery = Migrant::with(['Person.Ort', 'Land', 'Herkunft', 'Staat', 'Erfasser', 'Konfession', 'Betreuer', 'Aufenthaltsstatus', 'Arbeitserlaubnis']);

foreach($filter as $table=>$value){
    $mainQuery = $mainQuery->whereHas($table, function($q) use($value) {
        $q->where($value['key'], $value['operator'], $value['value']);
    })
}
return $mainQuery->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not do that, because I don't know how many filters I will get. I will update my question with some more explanation

Comment: I updated my question with an example query I want to do

Comment: Thanks, but when I would do it this way I would need to hardcode every possible table. I would rather be doing something like this:                 `return Migrant::with('Person.Ort', 'Land', 'Herkunft', 'Staat', 'Erfasser', 'Konfession', 'Betreuer', 'Aufenthaltsstatus', 'Arbeitserlaubnis')    ->whereHas('Person', function($q) use($filter) {
foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
    $q->whereHas($value['table'], function($q) use ($value) {
        $q->whereAnd($key, $value['operator'], $value['value']);
     });}})->get();`

Comment: yup. That would do. but does it work ? I mean it would depend on the structure of your `$filter`

Comment: It does not work. I get the following error: Details: Type:BadMethodCallException Message: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Land() (Land is the table I specifiy in the filter request)

Comment: which model includes `Land()` method ? Person ?

Comment: The Migrant model includes the Land method

Comment: Thanks, I dont get any errors now, but I get every immigrant who has a land like it would ignore the  $q->whereAnd($value['key'], $value['operator'], $value['value']);

Comment: Okay found the solution: I need to use $q->where and not $q->whereAnd! Thanks for you advice :)

Comment: ohh.. good.. Updated the answer to include `where` instead of `whereAnd`. thanks